# sublimetext typescript autoformat any tool available

Tags: typescript, sublimetext3

I am using SublimeText for TypeScript, so far I have been using JsFormat for auto formatting but this does not work for TypeScript.  Is there any other tool I can use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any other tool I can use for this

The Microsoft plugin for TypeScript supports it : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin

More : Shortcuts for formatting are mentioned here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin#features